# FIX - How to find status

Tags: fix-protocol

Im wringing a script that processes the FIX log files and reports a
summary about each file. I’m having trouble reading the order status (Tag 39). Where in the log is the broken down order status ? I don’t see where 39 could equal (39=1) or (39=4)

**Example log**

8=FIX.4.29=00011735=049=4G8287N50=ST156=CME57=G142=IL1603=3redatf1604=11605=3red34=252=20130808-13:29:37.291369=3112=TEST10=116
20130808-13:29:39.196 :

Answer (score 3):

This is a heartbeat, message type 35=0

[Fiximate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/) is your friend...

Comment: Fiximate is excellent. Also recommend https://fixparser.targetcompid.com for quick lookup and minifix client for testing

Comment: Thanks for the resource, but i would like to know how i can read it myself and see where the id is. I looked at their docs but they are not very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Well in a heartbeat message 35=0 you don't get an order id tag 39. Try looking at your data dictionary to see which messages contain the order id tag.